# Installing Oracle 8 JDK on Ubuntu

Tags: java, java-8, ubuntu-16.04, wget

I get the following error:

```
Setting up oracle-java8-installer (8u151-1~webupd8~0) ...
Using wget settings from /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/wgetrc
Downloading Oracle Java 8...
--2018-01-18 19:36:08--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 104.104.142.192
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|104.104.142.192|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
--2018-01-18 19:36:08--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 2a02:26f0:d2:280::2d3e, 2a02:26f0:d2:296::2d3e, 23.40.218.189
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|2a02:26f0:d2:280::2d3e|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1516304289_6e7f201fb7eb1023c58104b7dd4cdec1 [following]
--2018-01-18 19:36:09--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1516304289_6e7f201fb7eb1023c58104b7dd4cdec1
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|104.104.142.192|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2018-01-18 19:36:10 ERROR 404: Not Found.

download failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of default-jdk-headless:
 default-jdk-headless depends on openjdk-8-jdk-headless; however:
  Package openjdk-8-jdk-headless is not installed.
  Package oracle-java8-installer which provides openjdk-8-jdk-headless is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package default-jdk-headless (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of default-jdk:
 default-jdk depends on default-jdk-headless (= 2:1.8-56ubuntu2); however:
  Package default-jdk-headless is not configured yet.
 default-jdk depends on openjdk-8-jdk; however:
  Package openjdk-8-jdk is not installed.
  Package oracle-java8-installer which provides openjdk-8-jdk is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package default-jdk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                         Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
 default-jdk-headless
 default-jdk
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Somehow in the `/var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer` the `jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz` exists there and everytime I try to install or even `sudo apt-get autoremove` it throws the above error.

The link in the error message that Ubuntu is trying to get the JDK from doesn't exist on Oracle website anymore.

**Things I tried:**

- `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`
- `sudo apt-get clean`
- `sudo apt-get autoclean`
- `sudo apt-get autoremove`
- `sudo apt-get purge openjdk*`
- `sudo apt-get purge icedtea-* openjdk-*`
- `sudo apt-get install -f`
- I removed webupd8team from the software & update settings
- I erased the var/cache/apt/archives
- I removed the entire oracle-jdk8-installer folder with its content

Is there a way to change the wget settings and make this install happen?

Comment: This doc http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/07/31/install-oracle-java-8-9-ubuntu-16-04-linux-mint-18/ might be helpful

Comment: Someone else seems to have had this same problem and there is a possible solution at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/702274/error-while-setting-up-jdk8-on-ubuntu-14-04lts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that Oracle decided to just completely remove old version for download every time they release a new version. So they release **162** version today and removed **151** that is used by `web8upd` repository. For now, until the maintainer of the `web8upd` repository change the version, you can use this fix (hack):

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
sudo sed -i 's|JAVA_VERSION=8u151|JAVA_VERSION=8u162|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u162-b12/0da788060d494f5095bf8624735fa2f1/|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|SHA256SUM_TGZ="c78200ce409367b296ec39be4427f020e2c585470c4eed01021feada576f027f"|SHA256SUM_TGZ="68ec82d47fd9c2b8eb84225b6db398a72008285fafc98631b1ff8d2229680257"|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_151|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_162|' oracle-java8-installer.*
```

All credits here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2374686&page=4&p=13731177#post13731177

Just as a note this also happened when they updated to 151 version and will continue to happen in the future...

Comment: Worked as a charm.. thanks.. would you please explain what the about adjustments did to increase my knowledge and experience.

Comment: Yes. Basically you first downloaded java package from `web8upd` repo with broken link to oracle website and it throws 404 when downloading and stops the process. After that you go in the local copy of the repository and change download link to point to the latest java file (basically the change that will need to be done by the repo maintainer also). After that it tries to download java from a working link and it succeeds.